# specific cookie is present or not using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium

How to find cookie is present or not using selenium webdriver ?

```
 public bool CheckIfCookiePresent(bool empty)
 {
     Browser.Driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("cookie name");
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways, both practically identical. First one using LINQ, second using what you've already got but modified slightly:

```
public bool IsCookiePresent(string cookieName)
{
    return Driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Any(c => c.Name.Equals(cookieName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

vs:

```
public bool IsCookiePresent(string cookieName)
{
    return Driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed(cookieName) != null;
}
```